# Meaning of "to tie so. down" in sad song lyric

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does the marked line in this beginning of a song lyric mean?

> If this is how it's going to be for now
>   Then there's some little things that I would like to straighten out
>   'Cause I bet every trace is gone, delete the message from your phone
>   And just like that, it's like we never were
>
> Seems like every time you get a call you frown
>   **and don't you know that you don't need someone to tie you down?**
>   Still I see it in your eyes, there are a hundred reasons why
>   Still I don't know where to draw the line

I found that "tie someone down" can mean "to limit one's activities". Having the desperate-sounding question "don't you know?", can we conclude that the person the author sings about is in a new relationship and "tied down" by his/her new partner? At least they seem to have broke contact with each other recently.. Maybe a little far-fetched but I could not come up with a better explanation until now.

The song is "Loopholes" by Josie Charlwood, a girl from England. The complete lyrics can be found in the description of the video: https://youtu.be/lyXos9FlPRU[1](https://youtu.be/lyXos9FlPRU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To be tied down" is an idiom that means "to have responsibilities and obligations" or "to be restricted in one's choices because of responsibilities and obligations".

"someone to tie you down" would mean "someone who imposes obligations upon you in respect to themselves" or "someone to whom you would feel a sense of obligation" .

**I would like to go on a vacation but my student loans tie me down**.

**He would like to accept that job offer in New York, but because his wife is only halfway through her degree program and cannot leave Los Angeles, he is tied down at the moment.**

**He feels tied down when dating just one person, so he doesn't want to get too deeply involved at this stage of his life. He wants the freedom to take off on a trip at a moment's notice, with nobody depending on him.**